# Result of unused code in paradigm compiler

Tags: c, paradigms

Previously I was using Borland compiler for my project and currently switched to Paradigm compiler.

I came across a peculiar situation.  I have a piece of code which has no effect during execution.  This no-use code behaves/causes no issue when compiled in Borland, but causes some register corruption when compiled from Paradigm.  Following is the code block.

```
if (VarA == TRUE)
{
    //No code - for future implementation.
}
```

Once the IF case passes it will execute code inside the case, unfortunately that block will be implemented in future, so no code inside that.

Will Paradigm compiler really cause/corrupt any problem for this situation ?
or Paradigm is doing some optimisation during compilation ?

-- VP

Comment: Most probably due to adjacent code. If `VarA` is uninitialised then it's technically undefined behaviour. But only a truly nasty compiler would cause register corruption in that case.

Comment: VarA is assigned with some value and used for some comparisons above the mentioned code block.  Interesting point is, when I comment this block or keep some code like mentioned below, then it is not causing any issue.                                                              if (VarA == TRUE)
{
    VarA = 20;
}
        (or)
#if 0
if (VarA == TRUE)
{
    //No code - for future implementation.
}
#endif